# Triple tensor product with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, linear-algebra, tensorflow2.0

Suppose I have a matrix `A` and two vectors `x,y`, of appropriate dimensions. I want to compute the dot product `x' * A * y`, where `x'` denotes the transpose. This should result in a scalar.

Is there a convenient API function in Tensorflow to do this?

(Note that I am using Tensorflow 2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use** `tf.linalg.tensordot()`. [See the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot?version=stable)

As you have mentioned in the question that you are trying to find dot product. In this case `tf.matmul()` will not work, as it is only for cross product of metrices.

**Demo code snippet**

```
import tensorflow as tf

A = tf.constant([[1,4,6],[2,1,5],[3,2,4]])
x = tf.constant([3,2,7])
result = tf.linalg.tensordot(tf.transpose(x), A, axes=1)
result = tf.linalg.tensordot(result, x, axes=1)
print(result)
```

And the result will be

```
>>>tf.Tensor(532, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

**Few points I want to mention here**

1. Don't forget the `axes` argument inside `tf.linalg.tensordot()`
2. When you create `tf.zeros(5)` it will create a list of shape 5 and it will be like `[0,0,0,0,0]`, when you transpose this it will give you the same list. But if you create it like `tf.zeros((5,1))`, it would be a vector of shape `(5,1)` and the result will be

   ```
   [
   [0],[0],[0],[0],[0]
   ]
   ```

   Now you can transpose this and the result will be different, but I recommend you do the code snippet I have mentioned. In case of dot product you don't have to bother much about this.

If you are still facing issues, will be very happy to help you.

Comment: Thanks. Note that the `transpose` call is innecessary in `tf.linalg.tensordot(tf.transpose(x), A, axes=1)` (as you explain later in your post).

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following,

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([1,2])
a = tf.constant([[2,3],[3,4]])
y = tf.constant([2,3])


z = tf.reshape(tf.matmul(tf.matmul(x[tf.newaxis,:], a), y[:, tf.newaxis]),[])
print(z.numpy())
```

Returns

```
>>> 49
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `tf.transpose` and multiplication operator like this:
 `tf.transpose(x)* A * y` .

Comment: That doesn't work. You can try: `x = tf.zeros(5); A = tf.zeros((5,5)); tf.transpose(x) * A * x`, it returns a matrix instead of a scalar.

Comment: Is it a 1×1 matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example:

```py
x = tf.zeros(5)
A = tf.zeros((5,5))
```

How about

```py
x = tf.expand_dims(x, -1)
tf.matmul(tf.matmul(x, A, transpose_a=True), x)
```